# Error 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on subdomain I've created

Tags: css, .htaccess, cors

I've setup a static subdomain but when I try an access the fonts, I get this error.

I've looked around and was told to update my `.htaccess` file by adding `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` but to no avail, the message still appears. I've done this with all my `.htaccess` under the `public_html` folder.

Any suggestions we be appreciated.

> Access to Font at 'https://static.example.com/themes/template/fonts/fl-chapps.woff' from origin 'https:/example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config is setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in multiple places:

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

One way you *could* solve that problem is by not using `Header add`, but instead `Header set`:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

See [the Apache does for the `Header` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header):

```
set 
    The response header is set, replacing any previous header with this name.
```

But actually that’s probably unnecessary. You should instead remove one of the places where the header is being added; probably here:

> I've looked around and was told to update my `.htaccess` file by adding `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

You probably want to start by undoing that update, and see if that fixes the problem.

Your server seems already set to send the header, without you needing to update that `.htaccess`.